# angular2 subscribe to event emitted by another component

Tags: angular

I have a component that emits event as following:

```
@Output()
index: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

editGoals(goalId){

    this.editIdeasStepper=true;

    //emit goaldId so that it can be access in subgoals to load those subgoals
    this.index.emit(goalId);        

}
```

Is there any way that I can access/subscribe this emitted number in another component which is not child of this component? Or how to go about it?

Comment: The suggested way is to use a `Subject` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: So basically I create a service which will emit this number and then two independent components can subscribe to it?

Comment: Exactly and the service should be a singleton among these components.

Comment: And it is not necessary that these two components are children of a same parent? A shared service would do the job?

Comment: No relationship is required. The service will be the "meeting point" of the components.

Comment: Okay, let me try this! Thanks!